# odoo 11 showing more than one view in the same window

Tags: odoo-11

I am trying to create a view in odoo 11 that can perharps split the same screen and represent
more than one tree view of the same model on the same screen basing on filtering
**I am not trying to create dynamic tree view headers**

Comment: Do you want to make two views same like Quotations and Sale order?

Comment: Yes more like it, more like a dashboard, calling actions. it could actually be based on the same model but with each view showing different filters but on the same window

Comment: Then you can check the code for Sale order and Quotations menu.